# How to limit Single.Zip paralellism?

Tags: java, groovy, rx-java2

I am doing several http request, waiting for all the requests to complete, and with the information from all the request (and several other sources) calculate the result.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
Single.zip(observables, { array -> array })
```

Where observables is just an array of observables, each of them doing an async operation.

But I have a limit on how many operations I can do concurrently. There should be no more than n operations at the same time. (n being ideally 5 but 1 is accepted too)

Unfortunately Zip seems to start all the operations without waiting for any of them to complete. Is there a way to limit this behavior?

Comment: I'm not certain with Rx2, but I believe you should be able to set a custom Scheduler somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a combination of `window()` operator and `zip()`?
Something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flowable<Integer>[] flowables = new Flowable[] {
            Flowable.just(1), Flowable.just(2), Flowable.just(3), Flowable.just(4), Flowable.just(5),
            Flowable.just(6), Flowable.just(7), Flowable.just(8), Flowable.just(9)
    };

    Flowable.fromArray(flowables)
            .window(5)
            .flatMap(f -> Flowable.zip(f, objects -> Arrays.stream(objects).map(Object::toString).collect(joining("")))
                                  .flatMapSingle(Single::just))
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("received: " + s));


    Flowable.timer(10, SECONDS) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

The `window()` will split the flowables into a `Flowable` of `Flowable`s. Each flowable emitting only 5 elements (which can be the number of operations you want).
In this example, the `zip()` just concatenate the given integers.
It will print:

```
received: 12345
received: 6789
```

I hope this helps.